# Can't suddently ssh into home router

Tags: router, ssh

I've configured my home router and my pc at home to accept ssh connections, I've ssh into both the computer and the router multiples times with no problems at all. Today, while I was remotely logged in my home computer the connection suddently dropped.

So I tried to ssh into the router, I got prompted to add it to `known_hosts` (as always) but never got prompted for key/psw. Successive attemps resulted in no prompts for adding the host to `known_hosts` and "connection closed by host port 22".

An nmap scan show port 22 open (`sudo nmap -Pn <ip>`).

Weirdly a broader scan of adiacent ip addresses (I though my ip may have been changed `sudo nmap <3-ip-octets>.1/24`) skip the ip address of my router (guess is blocking ping probes now), although the ip didn't change and is scannable with -`Pn`.

How I debug this issue? It may be a temporary problem of my ISP or my router got compromised?

Comment: You need to be at home in order to analyze the problem.

Comment: makes sense... any suggestion for when I'll be home?

Comment: Restart the router and check port-forwarding. If you don't have internet, yell at your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

If your home Internet connection uses a dynamic IP address (one that can change) then it's most likely you've been assigned a new IP address.

There are tools to help get around the issue of not knowing the current address - look up Dynamic DNS (DDNS) services, for example - but in the meantime there is little you can do remotely.